# How to stop 'www' htaccess redirect adding on a second 'www'?

Tags: .htaccess

Currently here's my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{query_string} (^|&)p=contact$
RewriteRule (.*) /contact/

RewriteCond %{query_string} ^body=
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

So what the code does is during the HTML query in URL, any queries that has "p=contact" will be redirected to the contact page. While any query that has the word 'body' will be removed.

Now the code works brilliantly if I visit my site (e.g: example.com).

However, if I try to type www.example.com, it will load as www.www.example.com. It has double wwws. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to mention that the first line of rewritecond redirects non https to https links.

If I were to type www.example.com, it will redirect to https://www.example.com just fine.

However, if the link is www.example.com/?body=hi&p=contact, it becomes https:// www.www.example.com/contact/

Comment: have you tried removing the "www." from here: RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: you should first redirect everything non-www to www. then code whatever rules you want. the way it is now it is a complete mess.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I manage to solve it.

After hours of meddling with it, I realize if I change %{HTTP_HOST}% to my domain name it kinda makes it work perfectly.

Strange.